# Regex replacement with OR condition

Tags: regex, notepad++, regexp-replace

I have a list of strings (thousends) that are separated with whitespace and OR conditions, for example:

`Ani mal|Hu man|Pl ant|Fu ngus`

And I want to get rid of the whitespace but those strings are within a huge text (XML) with a lot of intentional whitespace. So I cannot just delete all whitespace. I tried:

`(Ani) (mal)|(Hu) (man)|(Pl) (ant)|(Fu) (ngus)`
  replace with:
 `$1$2`

obviously this does not work. I am aware that I could do that in any programming language but I wanted to see if there was a way to do it with Regex only (e.g. in Notepad++).

Comment: Use `(?|(Ani) (mal)|(Hu) (man)|(Pl) (ant)|(Fu) (ngus))`, replace with `$1$2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a fixed amount of groups per alternative, and you want to refer to the captured values (groups) in each alternative using *reset* indices you may leverage the [**branch reset group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
(?|(Ani) (mal)|(Hu) (man)|(Pl) (ant)|(Fu) (ngus))
^^^  1     2  ^ 1     2  ^  1    2  ^  1     2  ^
```

Replace with `$1$2`. Due to the `(?|...)` group, all the alternatives inside have groups with the same indices.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/45WLHH/1).

Notepad++ settings & demo:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't know about that possibility in regex!

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to find the alternative  I think I got it..
Find what: `(?<=Ani|Hu|Pl|Fu) (?=\w+)`
Replace with: `nothing`

[image]

Comment: This will replace the space in `Ab cd`, that is not wanted.

Comment: Yes. May be,  but I updated my answer, this for sure will only effect the intended strings....♥